# How to authenticate two types of user with same authentication callback in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook, omniauth-google-oauth2

I want to create a webpage using rails 6.0.0, which has two types of users(model) 
Admin
User/viewer

But the problems is that I want to authenticate (sign up /sign in) for both users with facebook or google_oauth2 with same callbacks address:
/auth/:provider/callback

On internet, github and youtube I have found articles and videos only for authenticate single model. But I want to authenticate (sign up /sign in) for two models.

Can anyone help?
Please give an idea to authenticate both model with some example that an beginner can understand.

Comment: Do you have authentication code (action) implemented for a single model? If so, add the code to the question.

Comment: I think same code should work and you can sign in for multiple types/model of users. BTW what issue are you facing? Also authentication doesn't have any relationship with user model/type. It is the Authorization part which should take care of access and not authentication

Comment: Hi @KrishnaPandit, I understand you accidentally posted/asked this question twice. See duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183514/how-to-authenticate-two-types-of-user-with-same-authentication-callback-in-rails You should close/delete this question, as the other one already has an answer, and continue there.